# Loading a sparse matrix in r from list

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Hi I have a file having a structure as follows

```
12    45    56
34    65    31
12    23    43
```

and so on I have a huge dataset

so I have text file having 3 columns but, the way I want to create the sparse matrix is that for each line say 12 45 56..... first number i.e is the row second number i.e 45 is column and third number(i.e 56) is the value at 12th row and 45th column of the sparse matrix

I do the following

```
>x = scan('data.txt',what=list(integer(),integer(),numeric()))
Read 61944406 records

> library('Matrix')
Loading required package: lattice
N
> N= sparseMatrix(i=x[[1]],j=x[[2]],x=x[[3]])
```

but I get this error

```
Error in validObject(r) : 
invalid class “dgTMatrix” object: all row indices (slot 'i') must be between 0 and nrow-1 in a TsparseMatrix
```

could anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `x[[1]]` you are refering to the first element of you x matrix, in this case `x[[1]]=12`. You must use `x[,1]` if you want index columms or `x[1,]` for rows.
Try this:

```
x = matrix(c(12,45,56,
             34,65,31,
             12,23,43), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)

N= sparseMatrix(i=x[,1], j=x[,2], x=x[,3])
```

EDITED: I have reproduced your error:

```
x = matrix(c( 0,45,56,
             34,65,31,
             12,23,43), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)

N= sparseMatrix(i=x[,1], j=x[,2], x=x[,3])
Error en validObject(r) : 
  invalid class “dgTMatrix” object: all row indices (slot 'i') must be between 0 and nrow-1 in a TsparseMatrix
```

So, make sure you don't have 0 in your 2 first colums

Comment: I want the final sparse matrix like this 
12th row 45th column is 56
34th row 65th column is 31 and so on

would your method give me that?

Comment: This gives me error in x[,1] : Incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: dude as you can see in the question I have  61944406 rows I wont be manually make a matrix out of that

Comment: First, use `str(x)` to see how your data is. Then, you can generate a matrix using `x=as.matrix(x)`. This should be work.

Comment: I think that you're getting a vector from `scan`. Try this: `x <- matrix(scan('data.txt'), ncol=3)`, and then try to create the sparse matrix

Comment: First of all thanks for you replies ..... I know the structure I think I should explain the structure..... so I have text file having 3 columns but, the way I want to create the sparse matrix is that for each line say 12 45 56..... first number i.e is the row second number i.e 45 is column and third number(i.e 56) is the value at 12th row and 45th column of the sparse matrix

Comment: The code I provide you do what you want. So I think your problem is the way you read your data. Please, try to read your data as `x <- matrix(scan('data.txt'), ncol=3)`. Then, verify if `x` is a matrix with `is.matrix(x1)` and its dimensions with `dim(x1)`. Finally, create your sparse matrix with `N= sparseMatrix(i=x[,1], j=x[,2], x=x[,3])`.

Comment: Oky is.matrix I am getting true
dim I am getting [1] 61944406 3 
and its giving me the same error again
rror in validObject(r) : 
invalid class “dgTMatrix” object: all row indices must be between 0 and nrow-1 in a TsparseMatrix

Comment: I see. Could you provive max values of 2 first columns? Note that the error tell you that row values (i) must be between 1 and nrow-1 (61944406-1)

Comment: oh! I see .... I would have to write a coed to figure that out ... I will update here as soon as I do that... Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same problem, after trying many things the solution came from reading the help for sparseMatrix function. The parameter index1 specify whether the index start from 1 or from 0.

```
N= sparseMatrix(i=x[[1]],j=x[[2]],x=x[[3]], index1=FALSE)
```